# 'C' program to pipeout audio file to FFMPEG and generate Video file

Tags: c, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am attempting to write a short 'C' program which reads in an Audio file using FFMPEG, processes that file using a 'C' program, and then outputs a file via FFMEPG, which combines the new, modified audio together with a Video representation using the FFMPEG showwaves filter.

At present the program attempts to do the following:-

i) Read in an audio file, using pipein thorugh FFMPEG
ii) Process the audio file using a portion of the 'C' program
iii) Pipeout the modified audio to FFMPEG, and generate a file using the 'showwaves' filter in FFMEPG to create an MP4 file with audio and video.

The following code run form the ommand line in FFMPEG generates the Audio/Video MP4 I want to create:-

```
ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i 12345678.wav  -i 12345678.wav  -filter_complex  "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a:0 -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart  12345678.mp4
```

"

This code generates a processed audio file, and outputs it to a .wav file as required:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
// Launch two instances of FFmpeg, one to read the original WAV
// file and another to write the modified WAV file. In each case,
// data passes between this program and FFmpeg through a pipe.
FILE *pipein;
FILE *pipeout;
pipein  = popen("ffmpeg -i 12345678.wav -f s16le -ac 1 -", "r");
pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i - out.wav", "w");

// Read, modify and write one sample at a time
int16_t sample;
int count, n=0;
while(1)
{
    count = fread(&sample, 2, 1, pipein); // read one 2-byte sample
    if (count != 1) break;
    ++n;
    sample = sample * sin(n * 5.0 * 2*M_PI / 44100.0);
    fwrite(&sample, 2, 1, pipeout);
}

// Close input and output pipes
pclose(pipein);    
pclose(pipeout);
}
```

(This code borrowed from ted Burke's excellent post [here](https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2017/02/10/a-simple-way-to-read-and-write-audio-and-video-files-in-c-using-ffmpeg/))

I have made an attempt as shown below, but this is not working:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
// Launch two instances of FFmpeg, one to read the original WAV
// file and another to write the modified WAV file. In each case,
// data passes between this program and FFmpeg through a pipe.
FILE *pipein;
FILE *pipeout;
pipein  = popen("ffmpeg -i 12345678.wav -f s16le -ac 1 -", "r");
pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i 12345678.wav  -i 
12345678.wav  -filter_complex  "
[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" 
-map 1:a:0 -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -
codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart  
12345678.mp4
", "w");


// Read, modify and write one sample at a time
int16_t sample;
int count, n=0;
while(1)
{
    count = fread(&sample, 2, 1, pipein); // read one 2-byte sample
    if (count != 1) break;
    ++n;
    sample = sample * sin(n * 5.0 * 2*M_PI / 44100.0);
    fwrite(&sample, 2, 1, pipeout);
}

// Close input and output pipes
pclose(pipein);    
pclose(pipeout);
}
```

Ideally someone can suggest an improved version of the pipeout command above - alternately another process to achieve this would be interesting

*** EDIT ***

Thanks to @Mulvya, the revised pipeout line is now:-

```
pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i -  -filter_complex  "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a:0 -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart  12345678.mp4
```

", "w");

On compiling with gcc I get the following error messages  :-

```
avtovid2.c: In function \u2018main\u2019:

wavtovid2.c:13:83: error: expected \u2018]\u2019 before \u2018:\u2019 
token
 pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i -  -
filter_complex  "
[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" 
-map 1:a:0 -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -
codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart  
12345678.mp4

^
wavtovid2.c:13:86: error: expected \u2018)\u2019 before 
\u2018showwaves\u2019
 pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i -  -
filter_complex  "
[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" 
-map 1:a:0 -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -
codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart  
12345678.mp4

^
wavtovid2.c:13:98: error: invalid suffix "x720" on integer constant
 pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i -  -
filter_complex  "
[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" 
-map 1:a:0 -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -
codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart  
12345678.mp4

^
wavtovid2.c:13:153: warning: missing terminating " character
 pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i -  -
filter_complex  "
[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" 
-map 1:a:0 -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -
codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart  
12345678.mp4

^
wavtovid2.c:13:86: error: missing terminating " character
 pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i -  -
filter_complex  "
[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" 
-map 1:a:0 -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -
codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart  
12345678.mp4

^
wavtovid2.c:14:6: warning: missing terminating " character
 ", "w");
  ^
wavtovid2.c:14:1: error: missing terminating " character
 ", "w");
 ^
wavtovid2.c:13:21: warning: passing argument 1 of \u2018popen\u2019 makes 
pointer from integer without a cast
 pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i -  -
filter_complex  "
[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" 
-map 1:a:0 -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -
codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart  
12345678.mp4
                 ^
In file included from wavtovid2.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:872:14: note: expected \u2018const char *\u2019 but 
argument is of type \u2018char\u2019
 extern FILE *popen (const char *__command, const char *__modes) __wur;
          ^
wavtovid2.c:13:15: error: too few arguments to function \u2018popen\u2019
 pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i -  -
filter_complex  "
[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" 
-map 1:a:0 -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -
codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart  
12345678.mp4
           ^ 
In file included from wavtovid2.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:872:14: note: declared here
 extern FILE *popen (const char *__command, const char *__modes) __wur;
          ^
wavtovid2.c:32:1: error: expected \u2018;\u2019 before \u2018}\u2019 
token
 }
```

Comment: You're reading from a pipe but your 2nd command is reading from a file, not the pipe. Your input in pipeout should be `-f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i -`. Also you can reuse and map the audio twice `-map 0:a`. No need to feed a 2nd input. Finally, ffmpeg does not edit files in place, so input and output files can't be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Mulvya - certainly the input file reading was wrong. Regarding mapping the audio - for the command to run properly within FFMEPG from the terminal I have found that I need to declare both the audio and video input files, otherwise 'showwaves' does not generate the video from the audio source. Still no joy though - the c compiler finds a number of errors with the syntax of the ffpmeg command.

Comment: Remove the double quotes around the filter_complex string and change `-map 1:a:0` to `-map 0:a`.

Comment: Thanks very much @Mulvya - stripping out the double quotes inside the ffmpeg string got the program to compile. (the compile command needs -lm to include math.h) . FFMPEG returns - [aac @ 0x90ae380] Too many bits per frame requested
- I have read somewhere that FFMPEG does not accept all Bandwidths and formats through pipe commands, so if anyone has any information about that it wold be very helpful...

Comment: That's an encoder limitation, not related to the pipes. Use `-b:a 256k`

Comment: @Mulvya many thanks for that. Interesting to note that from the Terminal command line the following command has been what I have needed to run in order to generate the video file I need :-    ffmpeg -i TEST_AUDIO_3.wav  -i TEST_AUDIO_3.wav  -filter_complex  "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a:0 -codec:v libx264 -crf 21 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 -movflags faststart  testaudio.mp4

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version - thanks to @Mulvya for help, and Ted Burke for the original code.

This program will read in a file named 12345678.wav via FFMPEG, process that file in 'C' to produce a tremolo effect, and then output the audio into a video file named 12345678.mp4, with video generated using the FFMEPG 'showwaves' filter :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
// Launch two instances of FFmpeg, one to read the original WAV
// file and another to write the modified WAV file. In each case,
// data passes between this program and FFmpeg through a pipe.
FILE *pipein;
FILE *pipeout;
pipein  = popen("ffmpeg -i 12345678.wav -f s16le -ac 1 -", "r");
pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i -  -filter_complex  
[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line:rate=25,format=yuv420p[v] -map [v] -
map 0:a  -codec:a aac -strict -2  12345678.mp4", "w");


// Read, modify and write one sample at a time
int16_t sample;
int count, n=0;
while(1)
{
    count = fread(&sample, 2, 1, pipein); // read one 2-byte sample
    if (count != 1) break;
    ++n;
    sample = sample * sin(n * 5.0 * 2*M_PI / 44100.0);
    fwrite(&sample, 2, 1, pipeout);
    }

    // Close input and output pipes
    pclose(pipein);    
    pclose(pipeout);
}
```

This still need some work to understand FFMPEG pipe limitations, and improve the output file specification.

The object of this program is to serve as the first step in developing programs which can accept and process audio files in 'C', and generate combined audio and video output using FFMPEG.